# How can I test only one bean using existing application's spring configuration class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-4

In my code, I don't want to load all the beans defined in the XXApplicationConfig class.

XXApplicationConfig is a @Configuration annotated file which has bunch of spring beans defined.

So, I want to load only AppBean from XXApplicationConfig class while testing to reduce loading test time and also differentiate what I am testing. I also want to load the class using XXApplicationConfig class to make sure the bean configuration defined is correct as well.

This is my Test class ( modified ) to test AppBean class.

Could you let me know if this is the right approach and suggest how to make it better? Currently, this approach seems to be working. But, not sure if it is correct way of approaching it.

```
@ContextConfiguration(loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class ApplicationTest {

    @Configuration
    @PropertySources(value = {@PropertySource("classpath:test.properties")})
    static class MyTestConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceHolderConfigurer()  {
            return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        }

        @Bean
        public XXApplicationConfig xxAppConfig() {
            return new XXApplicationConfig();
        }

        @Bean
        public CustomTestService customTestService() {
            return new CustomTestService();
        }

        @Bean
        public AppBean appBean() throws Exception {
            return XXApplicationConfig().appBean();
        }

    }

    @Autowired
    private AppBean appBean;


    @Test
    public void testAppBean() {
        test appBean.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to test just one object, just create one object of that class, using the constructor of that class. Spring beans are designed to be POJOs. The Spring context is just a convenient way of creating and connecting objects. Nothing stops you creating and connecting them yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you can instantiated the class you want to test and manually inject all the dependencies it required via constructor and/or setter getters, then you don't need to use Spring in your test.

However, if your bean:

1. uses private fields annotated with `@Autowired` or `@Value` without corresponding getters/setters.
2. depends on many other beans.
3. the behavior you want to test depends on Spring AOP/Proxies (you use `@Transactional` or `@Cacheable` for example).

Then you will need Spring to wired the bean. I personally prefer to define a a minimal `@Configuration` class for these cases.

Then again, if your bean meets the conditions on the list you should consider refactoring the bean to minimize its dependencies and facilitate testing.